# Why are parenthesis required for invoking methods with default arguments?

Tags: scala

I have a side-effect free method with default arguments that I'd like to invoke without parenthesis, e.g.:

```
scala> def foo(x: Int = 1) = 42
foo: (x: Int)Int

scala> foo
<console>:9: error: missing arguments for method foo in object $iw;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
              foo
              ^

scala> foo()
res3: Int = 42
```

Is this intentional, or just a temporary limitation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is probably intentional so you don't get parameter blocks disappearing on you:

```
def foo(x: Int = 2)(y: Int = 4) = x*y

foo(3)    // What does this mean???
```

Comment: I suppose, but it seems like ideally in the normal case (only 1 set of parameters), optional parens would be allowed.

Comment: Hm, this isn't covered in the [SID](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/completed/named-and-default-arguments.html), perhaps it could be added/covered? I haven't checked the spec...

Comment: As a workaround you can just write another method: `def foo(x: Int = 1) = 42; def foo: Int = foo()`